# How to configure Apache direct trust for CA signed certificates

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, certificate-authority

I'm working on a corporate network which unfortunately is flat and has led to an interesting security requirement which I'm sure is possible (I just can't figure out how)

The corperation has its own self signed CA which has signed certificates for both the client and the server, so far so normal but heres my problem I need to configure apache to trust only the signed certificates from a couple clients rather than all certificates signed by the self signed CA

I beleive this is called direct trust but am struggling to see how I implement it